# Why write_lock_irq is used rather then write_lock for the tasklist_lock?

Tags: c, linux, locking, kernel

In the Linux Kernel, read/write spin lock is used to synchronize access to the list of the tasks. However whereas read_(un)lock are used for reading, write_(un)lock_irq are used for writing. Why is it needed to disable interrupts while locking for writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a lock that's ever used in IRQ context, IRQs must be disabled when held. But there are different ways to achieve this.

(I describe spinlocks, read/write locks are the same in this respect)

- `spin_[un]lock` don't disable IRQs. Only use them when you know they're already disabled (e.g. in the interrupt handler).
- `spin_[un]lock_irq` disable/enable IRQs. Only use them when you know they're NOT disabled before calling the function.
- `sping[un]lock_irq[save|restore]` - disable IRQs, then return to the previous state. Can used regardless of IRQ state (at a small cost).

I guess the difference you see is due to the different calling contexts, not the read/write difference.

Comment: Even in process context in the copy_process the _irq variant is used, see [this](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.7.6/kernel/fork.c#L1396).

Comment: This matches what I said - `_irq` is used when IRQs are not disabled already, for example in process context.